# How to change a attributes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a 3rd party script which is setting a width and height on images, but for the life of me I can't figure out how it's doing it.  It's probably from the database or a class but there are a lot of them.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<img src="..." width="30px" height="30px">
```

Using jQuery, how can I change the height and width values?

I'm guessing it's something like:

```
$("..[$width="]").replace(
```

Here is the HTML of the element:

```
<div id="prodThumbnails">
<table style="width: 641px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="right" style="vertical-align: middle;">  
</td>   
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="productPhotoThumbnailSection">
<a onclick="javascript:drawMainImage('0', '')" href="javascript:swapImage()">
<img height="30" width="30" border="0" title="" alt="" 
src="images/products/85.png"/></a>
     
<a onclick="javascript:drawMainImage('1', '')" href="javascript:swapImage()"><img height="30" width="30" border="0" title="" alt="" 
src="images/products/90.jpg"/></a>
     
<a onclick="javascript:drawMainImage('2', '')" href="javascript:swapImage()">
<img height="30" width="30" border="0" title="" alt="" src="images/products/92.jpg"/></a>
</td>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: middle;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried doing this:

```
$(function() {
   $("td.productPhotoThumbnailSection img").attr("width","64px");
   $("td.productPhotoThumbnailSection img").attr("height","64px");

  });
```

but it keeps setting the image width and heights to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Thus, you want to set a new value for the `width` and `height` **attributes** of the element? You can do that with the [`attr()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) function.

Basic example:

```
element.attr('width', '100');
element.attr('height', '100');
```

or chained:

```
element.attr('width', '100').attr('height', '100');
```

or all at once:

```
element.attr({
    width: '100',
    height: '100'
});
```

Where in `element` can be for example `$('img')` to get all `<img>` elements, or `$('#imgId')` to get the specific `<img id="imgId">` element. See the [jQuery Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) section to learn more about selecting elements.

**Edit:** as response on your edit, after all you don't need the 'px' suffix in the `width` and `height` attributes, they are implicitly already in pixels. You only need the 'px' when you want to change the associated CSS properties such as `element.css('width', '100px');`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you i updated my post on the top what do you think it can be?

Answer (score 1):

assuming `<img id="blah" ...>` above:

```
$('#blah').attr({
  width: '30px',
  height: '30px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `attr( key, value )`?

You could do:

`$('img').attr('height', '50px');
$('img').attr('width', '50px');`

Comment: I tried this. For some reason, the value in the code is correct, but when that element is examined in Firebug, it retains the original value. So, in effect, nothing changed. I have an ID called #right. I want to change its width from 68% to 97% like this $("#right").attr("width", "97%");. Code says 97%, Firebug 68%. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Think #attr(key, value) should work here. More at the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery operates on the elements in the DOM, not the elements' attributes.

You need a selector that selects your img element and then edits your attribute.

```
$("img").attr('width', '35px')
$("img").attr('height', '35px')
```

You probably need a more specific selector than "img" though.  Do your images have a class or an id?

Comment: thank you i updated my post on the top what do you think it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the selector. Try

```
$('td.productPhotoThumbnailSection').children().children('img').attr({ width: '100',  height: '100'  })
```

I've tried that and that worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("td.productPhotoThumbnailSection img").attr({
    width: 64,
    height: 64
  });
});
```

Note that it is a simple number ("64") with no unit of measurement ("64px"). The latter is a valid CSS value but **not** a valid HTML value (for this attribute). The only valid unit of measurement in this context is a percentage.

See the [IMG element from the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) where height and width are of type %Length and [%Length is defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#Length) as:

> nn for pixels or nn% for percentage
>   length

ie "64px" is not valid.