# Change Rel attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiple occurrences of an  element with class of .gal_link, such as

```
<a href="" rel="shadowbox[gallery32];height=545;width=805" title="">Blah Blah</a>
```

What I am trying to do is find all occurrences of this on the page, and update the height and width to something like

```
<a href="" rel="shadowbox[gallery32];height=345;width=605" title="">Blah Blah</a>
```

I would imagine this should be easy but after searching high and low I can not find a straight forward way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

I was able to alert the rel for each link upon a click but can't see how to change attribute values once the page has loaded.

```
$('.gal_link').click(function(){
    var rel = $(".gal_link").attr('rel');
    alert(rel);
});
```

Again thanks.

Comment: If you read the documentation about `attr` properly, you will find out: http://api.jquery.com/attr/. Having a look at the documentation should always be the first step, before you search " high and low".

Comment: `$('.gal_link').attr('rel', 'my_new_rel_value');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a attributes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794191/how-to-change-a-attributes-with-jquery)

Comment: So in my example are width & height attributes of an element that it itself is an attribute of <a>

Comment: I am only looking to change width and height attributes of rel, not other values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass value you want to assign to attribute in second argument of [attr( attributeName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
$("selector").attr('rel', 'somevalue');
```

Comment: In your example I see rel is an attribute of .gal_link, so are width and height attributes of rel?

Comment: I just took an example you would not to know where and what to set in rel attribute

Comment: Thanks, I could see where that would be helpful if I wanted to change rel entirely, but I only want to change width and height. Again thank you though!

Comment: A colleague sent me this -   var galLinks = $(".gal_link");
galLinks.attr("rel", galLinks.attr("rel").replace("something", "somethingelse"));

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gal_link').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('rel', "shadowbox[gallery32];height=345;width=605" )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To run javascript once a page has loaded, you just need to surround the javascript code with:

```
$(function() {});
```

This tells the javascript inside to run once all the page is done loading.

If you are trying to change the height and the width of the element itself you could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.gal_link').height(345).width(605);
});
```

However, if you are trying to change the shadowbox properties in the rel of each link, you should do:

```
$(function() {
    $('.gal_link').attr('rel','shadowbox[gallery32];height=345;width=605');
});
```